# how to change format datapicker to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

how to make the datapicker format be like 2020-01-08

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
});

$("#tgl_mulai").on('changeDate', function(selected) {
  var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
  $("#tgl_akhir").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  }, 'setStartDate', startDate);
  if ($("#tgl_mulai").val() > $("#tgl_akhir").val()) {
    $("#tgl_akhir").val($("#tgl_mulai").val());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }` to format your datepicker.

Try:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
            });
```

```js
 $(function(){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
            });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
```

You can find the demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/WArtA/